# How to apply transition on div movement when upper disappears?

Tags: css, html, transition

I remove a div element using jquery 'fadeOut()', the problem is: when I remove an element, the other elements under this go up without transition and seems too abrupt. Don't know how to solve it. If I put transition on css into the class .publication the jQuery's fadeOut() stops working properly and remove the elements abrupt too.

How can I do this?

EDIT: And sorry for bad english...

EDIT2: Here's the Jsfiddle with my problem:

```
jsfiddle code
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zberQ/

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: Put a SHORT fiddle please: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: u want the space remain as it is!? or just avoid the jerk u r getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey you can use `opacity:0;` and then `slideUp()` which gives the desired effect....

Please see the following [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wizam/zberQ/2/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [slideUp()](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/).

You can also use `hide(500)` but I personally prefer the `slideUp(500)` effect.

`$('#yourelement').slideUp(500);`

It should animate all the rest of the elements as well.

**Per your comments, you can also use `.animate()` to create any custom animation you want:**

```
.animate({'height':'0','opacity':'0'});//in your specific case - $(this).parent().parent().animate({'height':'0','opacity':'0'});
```

or even create a squence of animation using `delay()`:

```
.animate({'opacity':'0.2'}).delay(50).animate({'height':'0','opacity':'0'});
```

The problem you are experiencing is the result of the [fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) behavior.
`fadeOut()` animates the opacity to 0 and then when it reaches 0 it sets the `display:none;`, making all elements jump up, down to fill out the empty space.
From jQuery documentation:

> The .fadeOut() method animates the opacity of the matched elements.
>   Once the opacity reaches 0, the display style property is set to none,
>   so the element no longer affects the layout of the page.

[slideUp()](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/) animates the height first, causing a smooth disappearnce, than sets display:none;. Taken from jQuery documentation:

> The .slideUp() method animates the height of the matched elements.
>   This causes lower parts of the page to slide up, appearing to conceal
>   the items. Once the height reaches 0 (or, if set, to whatever the CSS
>   min-height property is), the display style property is set to none to
>   ensure that the element no longer affects the layout of the page.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cMk8T/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried it right now, but don't know where to put this line of code. I'm using JQuery but I don't know anything about Jquery for now...

Comment: instead of fadeOut() put slideUp(500)

Comment: Is there any way to get both effects? fadeOut alone is abrupt and slideUp alone is ugly... Thanks a lot for the tip anyway!

Comment: @Lloople ugly is a matter of perspective. It's much cleaner than fadeOut() in my opinion and very commonly used in responsive design. Try using hide(500) which is something in the middle...

Comment: just revised my answer, you can use animate() to create any custom effect you want. This should do the trick! :)

Comment: Thank you for all your time and dedication, green wizard just show me the exactly effect I want but I really apreciate your lessons about JQuery :)